# PHP - XMLWriter sometimes works but most times outputs an empty string

Tags: php, xml, php-5.3, xmlwriter

I have a weird behaviour while testing the following basic XMLWriter code in PHP:

```
    $x = new XMLWriter();
    $x->openMemory();
    $x->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $x->setIndent(true);
    $x->startElement('testrow');
    $x->writeElement('test', 'moretest');
    $x->endElement();
    $x->endDocument();
    var_dump($x->outputMemory());
```

Outputs an **empty string** most of the times. `startDocument()`, `writeElement()` etc. return **false** in that case.

But sometimes reloading the page produces the desired xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testrow>
    <test>moretest</test>
</testrow>
```

This happens roughly 1-2 out of 10 reloads. I don't know what is going wrong here, as it should produce the xml code every time?